# Tool tip with close button

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I need a tool tip. By hover the text, the tool tip will appear. By clicking the page or pressing escape key or click the close button, the popup will close. Is it possible? I need your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download) extensively for this, and this functionality is mostly available out of the box with it.  So far, it's the only one I've found that effortlessly incorporates ThemeRoller, at least until jQuery UI rolls out their own tooltips in v 1.9 early next year.

Comment: I search many websites and found a tool tip with close button. But the problem is the tool tip is close, by clicking the close button. otherwise it is not close.

Comment: Please refer the following location. http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Comment: cluetip is nowhere near as mature as qTip is....which is why I strongly recommended qTip.  My suggestion is to not obsess so hard about a close button.  I do UI design/development for a living, and none of my large clients have had such a requirement.  Users are used to modals without close buttons, and you could use something like a delayed close if you're afraid they won't be able to interact with the tips effectively.

Comment: Some more examples: http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/ http://scripterlative.com/files/ultimatips.htm                           http://www.thewindowsclub.com/start-button-tooltip-text-changer-windows-7-released

Comment: oh, btw, stay well away from prototip if you're using jQuery.  Prototype (which it is built on) and jQuery don't play friendly, and it will cause massive overhead issues.

Comment: Ok. I will search and find a solution. If I have find, I will post the solution. Thanks.